# Inaccurate position of inverse search with xelatex+sumatraPDF

Tags: xetex, forward-inverse-search

It seems that the `xelatex` engin has some "bug" when work with sumatraPDF, the position is not correct! The same doc when compiled with `pdflatex` work prefectly.

I really don't know what's the problem!

**UPDATE**

As the comments require an example to show the problem, I will make this clear in what follows.

Firstly, my version of TeX is `CTeX v2.9.2.164` (this is not important at all, just a repack of `MiKTeX 2.9`), and my editor is `WinEdt 7.0` with standard default setting, the pdf viewer is the default `SumatraPDF 2.0`. Let me also explain the inverse search setting:

1. make sure that the `--src` is show in WinEdt when you compile the test doc;
2. make sure in the pannel `WinEdt->Options->Execution Modes->PDF Viewer`, `PDF Viewer Executable` is pointed to the right path of `SumatraPDF.exe` and the `Sync TeX` option `Use --synctex switch when --src is enabled` is `checked`! (Since the paramenter is standard `--synctex=1` & `.synctex.gz`, I ignore to show this)
3. make sure the `SumatraPDF setting->option->inverse search command` be `"PathOFWinEdt.exe" "[Open(|%f|);SelPar(%l,8)]"`
   I believe that all of these stuff are necessary and sufficient for the inverse search works!

Now, let me give the example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  %\lipsum[3-56]
  Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna.

Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim. Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.

Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus
nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta vehicula.

Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus, ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor. Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis. Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo lectus sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo. Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est. Curabitur consectetuer.

Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet, laoreet vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum at, molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor odio, commodo pretium, ultricies non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy in, fermentum faucibus, egestas vel, odio.

Sed commodo posuere pede. Mauris ut est. Ut quis purus. Sed ac odio. Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio. Morbi ut dui. Sed accumsan risus eget odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque non elit. Fusce sed justo eu urna porta tincidunt. Mauris felis odio, sollicitudin sed, volutpat a, ornare ac, erat. Morbi quis dolor. Donec pellentesque, erat ac sagittis semper, nunc dui lobortis purus, quis congue purus metus ultricies tellus. Proin et quam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Praesent sapien turpis, fermentum vel, eleifend faucibus, vehicula eu, lacus.
\end{document}
```

Save it as a utf8 encodding doc, and compile it with the engin `xelatex` and `pdflatex` respectively. Try to double click a paragraph of the output pdf, you shall see the `pdflatex` compiled doc will bring you to the right position in the editor, but `xelatex` is not.

Hope this will help to find the problem and what's more important solve the problem.

Comment: Could you give a small example of your document? Like this, we do not have to set up the problem for you. Which TeX-editor are you using? We will also need your configuration of compilation. Maybe, you are not calling `synctex` when running XeLaTeX

Comment: @LaRiFaRi update are provided!

Comment: I have no problems with MiKTeX 2.9, SumatraPDF 3.0 and WinEdt 9.0.